# Unit testing classes weaved by aspects with dependency injected Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, aop, aspectj

Because Spring-driven AspectJ LTW is unable to weave classes loaded before Spring initializes, I'm converting a Spring project to pure Aspectj LTW (with the AspectJ weaver java agent).

However, this collaterally enables AOP in our Unit Tests because I need to add AspectJ's agent to the Maven Surefire plugin argLine parameter and to the default TestNG configuration in my team's IDE (IntelliJ IDEA).

This wouldn't be a problem if our Aspects were not dependent on Spring, but some of them actually require Spring beans to be injected in their fields via @Resource notation. As Spring is not started during Unit Tests, that fields will be null and result in NullPointerExceptions.

Even though I could configure two independent executions of the Surefire plugin during the build process: one with the agent and the other without it; this solution would become impractical as each developer would still need to change the IDE's test configuration for unit tests vs other tests that actually require AOP and start Spring, for every independent test execution (i.e. outside of Maven build process).

What would be the best approach in order to solve this problem? Is there any way to disable AspectJ's LTW while still keeping the java agent configuration intact? Or maybe another and more flexible way to configure AspectJ's LTW that doesn't have the problems of Spring-driven AspectJ LTW?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks. Otherwise please answer it by yourself ans accept your own answer, no problem.

Comment: I have already up voted your answer a long time ago. I didn't consider it as the answer, because it didn't actually solve my problem. However, I think what I was asking for is impossible (I ended up asking everyone to manually adding and removing the javaagent for unit vs integration tests), so your solutions constitute what can effectively be done. I will accept it as the answer on this premise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could argue about whether or not it is a good design decision to make pure AspectJ aspects dependent on Spring magic or if it would be an option to inject mock-ups for your Spring beans into the aspects. Actually a unit test is not a unit test if it requires such a framework. The same is arguably true for aspects.

Anyway, here is a cheap solution: Use [`if()` pointcuts](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697) for all relevant advice and make them dependent on whether you are in testing mode or not. The performance overhead will usually be minimal, don't worry. Just give it a try before you say it is too expensive.

Also possible, but more expensive would be to determine if a test class is in the control flow of the currently intercepted joinpoint via `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()`. I do not recommend it in this case though.

A third option might be to add another *META-INF/aop.xml* to the classpath in testing mode which contains a global *exclude* statement excluding all classes from weaving. The [AspectJ documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files) explains how multiple *aop.xml* are merged logically. Probably this option is the best because it does not require you to change your aspects. I have not tried, but I would if you encounter any difficulties and give me a sign.

Comment: Thanks. I had the exact same doubt about whether a unit test should be dependent on the tested-class' aspect. I also think this is not the desired solution as making the test aware of the aspect is very AOP and unit-test unfriendly. That's why I was trying to solve the problem by disabling AOP during the unit tests. I will start by looking into your last suggestion. Thanks again.

P.S.: I only didn't understand your point regarding pure AspectJ aspects and Spring DI. Isn't it what factory-method="aspectOf" is all about? What's so wrong about it?

Comment: What I mean is that AspectJ is independent of Spring and/or Spring AOP. For instance, I use AspectJ a lot in stand-alone Java SE programs without any Spring.

Comment: I know they are independent, I was just asking why do you think it can be a bad design decision to use Spring to populate AspectJ aspects, as it seems a common operation (and AspectJ enjoys SpringSource sponsorship so I think they have the most interest in supporting Spring integration).
Regarding the different aop.xml, I guess it won't be possible because in our project we have different type of tests in the same package (probably not a very good idea I agree) so I can't differentiate between unit tests and e.g. integration test without introducing the same problems as previously stated.

Comment: Ah, that. As I said, we *could* argue, but I do not want to. It is fine, let us just concentrate on the problem at hand. As for your test package structure: IDEs permit for easy refactoring. `;-)` Besides, you can still have a launch configuration for unit tests in Maven as well as IDE, what is the big problem? The launch config can then set a switch or add a directory to the classpath. Give it a try, it cannot be that hard. You do want to unit-test, do you not?

Comment: I know I can create multiple test configurations in Maven, but in IDEA I'm not sure if I can have per test-group configurations (that's why I created this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638983/default-run-configuration-per-testng-group-in-intellij-idea - 1 hour ago :) )