# Default run configuration per TestNG group in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

Is there any way in Intellij IDEA 12 to create a default TestNG run configuration on a per TestNG group basis, so I can give a different VM option for each one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jetbrains, this is currently not possible.

[Reference](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5492678)